# Сборка gitlabci без кеширования

Tags: docker, gitlab, непрерывная-интеграция, gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner

Возможно ли запускать сборку в gitlab ci без кеширования, или очищать кеш после каждой сборки?
Возможно нужно внести изменения в gitlab-runner?
Использую docker executor

Пример пайплайна:

```
image: node:latest

stages:
  - publish

publish:
  stage: publish
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run build
    - cd dist/ && npm publish --registry http://192.168.11.12
```

Comment: Что именно вы имеете ввиду под кешированием? Что за сборка? Java? Покажите код CI/CD, пожалуйста.

Comment: Код CI дополнил в вопросе. Проблема в том, что если сборка npm завалилась, и не очистить кеш - после исправлений сборка тоже завалится. Очищаю кеш либо по кнопке в гите, либо удаляя docker volumes вручную на ВМ, где установлен gitlab-runner, но это не удобно. Ищу способ решить эту проблему.

Comment: Что-то ты нам тут не договариваешь. По-умолчанию никакие пользовательские файлы не будут кэшироваться, в этом смысл и gitlab ci и использования докера

Comment: Дело в том что при использовании gitlab-runner docker executor - при выполнении пайплайна создаются docker volumes - которые используются при следующих запусках задания. Как я понял туда и сохраняется репозиторий. Ниже я описал способ решения этой проблемы.

Comment: "Как я понял туда и сохраняется репозиторий. " - нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После изучения документации выяснил, что при использовании docker executor gitlab-runner создает docker volumes, куда кеширует данные.
Отключение создания тома производится в конфигурационном файле gitlab-runner

```
/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml

...
disable_cache = true
...
```